# load javascript in views

Tags: python, django

I am new to django. Is there any way to load javascript in .py files? I need to access a json, defined in one of my .js files in the middle of one of my functions in a .py file. How is that possible?

**update:**

json in my chart-options.js file is:

```
var theme = {
    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },

    lang: {
        thousandsSep: thousand_separator_symbol,
        decimalPoint: ".",
        numericSymbols: null
    },
.
.
.
.
```

and in my function in views.py:

```
.
.
options =  get_default_options()
// here I need to access the theme and have chart_options = theme from .js
options.update(chart_options)
.
.
.
.
```

tnx

Comment: Please paste the json and view code by editing the question!

Comment: done! @AbijithMg

Comment: You might want to look at https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AJAX

Comment: Do not use .js to specify JSON object. Better is to paste it in .json file and then based on your project path it can be easily read in your views.py.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [minAjax](http://flouthoc.github.io/minAjax.js/) to pass data to the backend. You can use [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/blob/master/src/js.cookie.js) to create csrftoken in case you are using the POST method.

Here's an example:

```
var theme = ...
var csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken');
minAjax({
   url:"/url/",//request URL
   type:"POST",//Request type GET/POST
   //Send Data in form of GET/POST
   data:{
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken, 
        theme: theme,
        },
   //CALLBACK FUNCTION with RESPONSE as argument
   success: function(data){
       //use the data returned from backend here;
        alert(data);
       }
});
```

and the backend:

```
import json
def yourfunction(request):
   theme = request.POST.get('theme', '')
   if theme:
      json.loads(theme) #convert to python diction
   theme = json.dumps(theme) #convert back to json string
   return  render(request, 'template.html', {'theme':theme})
```